# Fill font awesome icon with loading animation

Tags: html, css

### Issue

I am trying to use a font awesome icon `fas fa-cannabis` and add a fill effect, now I have part of the CSS down, I can see the loading animation but I can't get it to fill inside the font awesome icon. So all I basically want to do is put that fill effect that you can see below inside of the font awesome icon.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pierrepdp/pen/gEZOYx) for the question

At the moment it is sitting underneath the font awesome icon. Which you can see below:
[image: Failed loading effect]

---

### Code

So my HTML is as follows:

```
<i class="fas fa-cannabis" id="banner">
  <div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</i>
```

With the following CSS that is creating the fill effect:

```
#banner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#banner .fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width:300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}
@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}
@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mix-blend-mode:screen;` For this I'm wrapping both the `i` and the `fill` in a div and set `i{position:absolute}`. Please take a look at the [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/980217779052ee60f3c48aa09ce9da44)

```css
#wrap{height: 150px;
  width:150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid;
}
#banner {
  height: 150px;
  width:150px;

}
.fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
}
#waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width:300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;

}
@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}
@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
i{font-size:147px; background:#fff;}


#wrap i{position:absolute}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<i class="fas fa-cannabis" id="banner"></i>
<div class="fill">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use clipping paths to apply the fill only to the icon. You might also need to use an svg rather than an icon...

This article has some interesting info that may help: https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/

Comment: Unfortunately didn't make a difference. I can create an example in codepen if that will help?

Comment: looks like the inline width and height of the svg tag is causing part of the problem,

Comment: If I remove it then the animation becomes all weird though. And I am trying to get it to fill the inside of the font awesome icon, not over it. I'm not sure if this might be easier with SVGs?

Comment: ah i see what you mean. you might be able to use the icon as a clipping mask, so that only the icon is 'filled'. or an animation utility might help too. greensock.js has a bunch of cool svg animations for example. I forked your pen, it fills over the top of the icon though... https://codepen.io/johncurtin/pen/ZPVEYZ?editors=1100

Comment: Think I am going to have to go the SVG route to be able to clip the animation.